# appcelerator titanium_prep.macos Android module build failure on Mac OSX

Tags: android, macos, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am attempting to build a `CommonJS` module in `Appcelerator Studio`.

Following this recipe:

1. File > New > New Mobile Module Project
2. Set the project name to be `testmodule`
3. Leave the location as default
4. Set the Module Id to `au.com.test.testmodule`
5. Set the Titanium SDK Version to `5.3.1.GA`
6. Set the Deployment Targets to `Android`
7. Click `Next` and then `Finish`

This will create a new module called `testmodule`.

Under this folder there is a one called `assets`, create a new file in there called `au.com.test.testmodule.js`. This will mark the module as a `CommonJS` module.

In this file just create an empty function and export it

```
function test() {
  Ti.API.debug('test');
}

module.exports = test;
```

From the command line type:

```
ant
```

This will attempt to build the module.

In output you will see the ant target `js.compile` and this will have an error message

> [exec] [DEBUG] "/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.1.GA/android/titanium_prep.macos" au.com.example.testmodule /testmodule/android/build/generated/js au.com.example.testmodule.js
>
> [exec] [ERROR] Not enough arguments.
>
> [exec] [ERROR] Unabled to prepare JavaScript for packaging. Error code 1.
>
> [exec] Result: 1

Running ant like the following:

```
ant -debug -logfile build.log
```

The problem seems to be an executable called `titanium_prep.macos`.

If you run the command

```
"/Users/chris/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.3.1.GA/android/titanium_prep.macos" au.com.example.testmodule /testmodule/android/build/generated/js au.com.mobilogica.testmodule.js
```

It will give the error `Not enough arguments`. If you add one more parameter of anything, it will run without giving that message.

Of course being that the parameter is bogus, it will not generate the correct code.

It seems like `titanium_prep.macos` requires 4 parameters, but right now only three are being passed in.

1. au.com.example.testmodule
2. /testmodule/android/build/generated/js
3. au.com.example.testmodule.js

System:

- Mac OSX 10.10.5
- XCode 6.1
- Appcelerator CLI 5.4.0
- Appcelerator SDK 5.3.1

If you generate the example same module with `3.5.1.GA` it works.

I have tried this in the `4.4` series of SDKs as well and have the same problem.